# Excel 2010 How to compare two sets of numbers that don't match but are related and return true/false result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, comparison

I am trying to compare two sets of numbers but they have different formats (the length of one number is different in each list) but parts of them match. I want to find the matches and return a YES response and the ones that have no match return a NO response in a new column. Since the number format is different, VLOOKUP isn't an option.

The numbers I am comparing are on different sheets in the same workbook.

I am fairly new at Excel and am trying all kinds of ways but haven't found one that does the trick yet. I should also add that the main number I am comparing TO is in Workbook 1 as it contains more information. I am pulling it to the workbook 2 where the Yes/No response will be recorded.

Here is an example:

```
Workbook 1
Column A
1234567890
1234512345
1234561234
2345789000

Workbook 2
Column A
123456789
123451234
3456123
345678901
```

Here's what it would look like:

```
Workbook 2
Column A     Column B
123456789    Yes
123451234    Yes
3456123      Yes
345678901    No
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Note*
One options I've been trying to use is =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B3,'Workbook 1'!$A$1:$A$100)), "Yes", "No")

Will this work for what I need to do? It seems that it is finicky...

Comment: Help us to help you....  **Post an example.**

Comment: I have updated the main post.

Comment: Which ones are meant to return `YES`?

Comment: I am trying to compare the two columns in different workbooks and find a match. I am working with 11 and 12 digit UPCs and want to match them up and provide a "Yes" response to good matches. Those that don't have a match should return a "No" response.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with how 11 and 12 digit UPC codes "match", what is the rule?  Which records in your example should get a Yes and which should get a No?  Between your question, the edit, and your comment, you still have not defined what you want to accomplish in Excel.

Comment: Example: 008274999990 is a 12 digit UPC on Workbook 1. I have to match that to the same UPC recorded as an 11 digit UPC on Workbook2 which is recorded as 827499999 or 12 digit UPC as 8274999990. The formatting is not consistent so it would be difficult to format for vlookup, which is my challenge.

Comment: Think of it as comparing numbers that don't evenly match, but I have to find common numbers between two columns of numbers. When a match is found I want it to return a YES response and if there is no match to return a NO response. Ideally, I'd like one to be compared to the other and return the proper result.

Comment: Your comment shows 10 digits for a 12 digit code and 9 digits for a 11 digit code.  Is it only leading and trailing zeros that can be ignored, or do you just need to find the shorter code somewhere in the longer code?

Comment: That's the exact issue I am trying to overcome, you hit the nail on the head. It isn't just a leading or trailing zero, but they are mix-and-match. You are right in saying that I need to find the shorter one in the longer one. Ideally, the 12 digit should have most or all of what the 10 digit has.

Answer (score 0):

In Workbook1, you can put a formula in the next column, which cuts away the last char and looks it up in the other workbook:

`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),Workbook2!$A$2:$A$100,1,FALSE)`

this would give you a the found match, or an error. If you like "YES" or "NO", you can embed it into an IF:

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),Workbook2!$A$2:$A$100,1,FALSE),"NO","YES")`

Note that you will need to adjust `Workbook2!$A$2:$A$100` to match your data in workbook 2. Then, copy that formula down for all lines.

Comment: Neither one of these seemed to work. I got an #N/A response for all items using the first formula. And I got all "YES" response when using the second formula. I am not sure what I may have done incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This formula must be **array-entered**:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(A1,[Book2]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6))),"Yes","No")
```

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
`ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place curly braces `{...}` around the formula.